# Set document background image in code

Tags: asp.net, .net, image, background

I can use VS designer to open the document properties and change the Background property. But I can't seem to find a way to change it dynamically when the page loads. Can this be done in codebehind or this must be done in JavaScript only?

Comment: What's wrong with plain old CSS?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try this on the markup:

```
<head runat="server">
   <title></title>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</head>

<body class="bodyStyle">
```

And this in the codebehind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            String ImgUrl = "/Images/image.png";
            Literal1.Text = "<style>.bodyStyle {background-image: url('" + ImgUrl + "');}</style>";
        }
    }
```

You can programmatically change the image url as needed

Comment: -1: The `<style>` element should only ever appear within the `<head>` section of the HTML. Your code will not do that.

Comment: That's not a very good example - one shouldn't write to the response in `Page_Load`. Plus `style` should only ever be inside `head`.

Comment: First of all, it was a simple example how to do it, and YES it does work, try it!!!

Comment: @AntLaC It's invalid HTML. Just because the browser renders it that doesn't make it valid. You can check the HTML specification which is clear on `STYLE`.

Comment: If you read his question he states he wants to dynamically change it, you cannot do that in plain old CSS

Comment: You can also have a style tag within the body

Comment: @AntLaC you can have a `style` attribute in the `body` element but not a `style` element. That's invalid HTML. Check the HTML specification.

Comment: I wrapped up the style code in a Literal control in the Head section, loading it in the Page_Load event. Is that a correct way?

Comment: @LoveDotNet Yes, there's nothing wrong with that. As long as your `STYLE` gets written to the `HEAD` your output is fine.

Comment: @LoveDotNet Yes, that will wil work, I've update my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `background` and, more specifically, the `background-image` CSS properties.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

You can either generate the relevant HTML output on the server (using ASP.NET code) or in the browser, using JavaScript. Your HTML will look something like this:

```
...
<body style="background-image:url('...')">
...
</body>
...
```

Comment: this doesn't answer his question

Comment: @AntLaC I don't see why not. It's essentially what you answered (just for the record, I posted it before you) and it does actually work and is correct. If the poster wants to dynamically change it, (s)/he can use JavaScript or server-side code.